# Any tips for organization-wide 2FA enforcement?

Tags: account-security, multi-factor

I'm hoping to lead my organization (around 15 people, all remote) in overhauling our security practices, and part of that is making sure each team member is using 2FA on the platforms/tools that offer it. Anyone have any tips for how to go about this? Any tools or centralized knowledge bases for walking people through how to set up app-based 2FA on all our platforms?

Comment: For tool recommendations, use https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: With such little information it's hard to give recommendations, can you elaborate a bit more about your environment? Azure/AWS/on-prem?

Comment: There are lots of videos on YouTube on how to set up 2FA on various platforms.

Comment: As already mentioned we need your threat model and more information about your current security posture.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a scrum/agile based on approach. If you use Azure and M365 that makes it easier I think, because if enable 2FA there, all the connected workloads, like mail and SharePoint Online are also protected using 2FA.

1. So first arrange backing and support of management on all levels.
2. Communicate and engage the business to prepare them.
3. Then enable 2FA for a few test user and maybe let a few power users from the business also test with 2FA enabled.
4. Then step by step integrate more and more workloads/applications
   with 2FA and always communicate in advance to the business of
   upcoming changes.